# Woocommerce: get product ID from variation sku

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm creating a webshop, that imports a lot of products from a csv file. I need to link to available accessories etc., which individually is determined and imported by the respectable products SKU.

I know it is possible to get the product ID with a simple products SKU with this:

```
wc_get_product_id_by_sku('PRODUCT_SKU');
```

Is there anyway to do the same, but with a variation sku?

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT:** It seems that you can now use wc_get_product_id_by_sku() to retrieve a product_variation without any problems, see the other answer below.

I was stuck on a very similar problem. I couldn't find anything in the woocommerce code that would let you directly look up the parent product from the variation sku.
But, as product variations are stored in the `wp_posts` table with the type `product_variation`, and the SKUs are stored in the `wp_post_meta` table,  it's easy to look up the product variation using a meta query with the `get_posts()` wordpress function.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product_variation',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'   => '_sku',
            'value' => 'PRODUCT_SKU',
        )
    )
);
$posts = get_posts( $args);
```

This should return your matching `product_variation` custom post type.

Once you have this then you can look up the parent product using the column `post_parent` that WooCommerce uses to link a variation to the parent variable product.

Turning that into a function is pretty straight forward:

```
function wc_get_product_id_by_variation_sku($sku) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'product_variation',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'   => '_sku',
                'value' => $sku,
            )
        )
    );
    // Get the posts for the sku
    $posts = get_posts( $args);
    if ($posts) {
        return $posts[0]->post_parent;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I use this in my site and it works great. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe not name it as you have in case WC eventually write a function with the same name ;)

Comment: Sir, reading 'product_variation' has solved what I have been working on tonight. If we were in the same room, I would owe you a drink. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to get Variation ID using `wc_get_product_id_by_sku` function then get post parent ID to get Product ID.

```
$variation_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku('VARIATION_SKU');
$product_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($variation_id);
```

Comment: This code doesn't work because it looks up the sku on "products" post type. You can see the implementation here: http://hookr.io/functions/wc_get_product_id_by_sku/ 

Variations are stored as "product_variation" post type, so it needs a custom function to find a product with a variation sku.

Comment: These are the default woocommerce functions and works fine for me. `wc_get_product_id_by_sku` returns product id and that's obviously of "product_variation" post type but then `wp_get_post_parent_id` is used to get parent product and that will be of "products" post type. I hope this clarifies your point.

Comment: You are correct Abhijit, that seems to work fine now. Maybe when I wrote the answer back in 2018 the API was slightly different. I'm sure `wc_get_product_id_by_sku` didn't work for me then. the hookr.io link in my last comment doesn't seem to work anymore either, so I can't check. I'll edit my original answer and point them to your response.